# How can I copy network files using Robocopy?

Tags: robocopy

How can I copy network files using Robocopy?

Answer (score 38):

I use the following format and works well.

```
robocopy \\SourceServer\Path \\TargetServer\Path filename.txt
```

to copy everything you can replace `filename.txt` with `*.*` and there are plenty of other switches to copy subfolders etc... see here: http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: Will robocopy route the traffic via the machine it is executed on (Source --> RoboCopy Machine --> Target) or will it direct the files directly from source to target (Source --> Target) and thus not cause (except for messaging overhead) network load on the machine it runs on?

Comment: @Ahue good question, as it runs out of the box with no need to install anything on target or source machines I am pretty sure it runs only from the machine you start it in command prompt, which means that if you run it from machine C to copy files from A to B files will kind of go A to C to B, in my understanding, because the bytes are moved by robocopy which will open streams / sockets or whatever buffers in the machine where it runs from.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Windows "UNC" paths with robocopy.  For example:

```
robocopy \\myServer\myFolder\myFile.txt \\myOtherServer\myOtherFolder
```

Robocopy has the ability to recover from certain types of network hiccups automatically.

Comment: this is actually the wrong format, file name should NOT be included in the source path.

Comment: Edited to show correct format in example.

Comment: Check the following answer for correct command. File name should be at the end